# AWS-Elastic Beanstalk- How to shut down a machine automatically based on a condition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have an Elastic Beanstalk application. It seems like after running for a while, the servers' CPU utilization starts climbing to 40-50 percent even with no load which slows the website response.

Is there a way to automatically shut down instances that stay above a certain threshold like 40% for more than a few hours so that they can be replaced by new machines?

The scaling group policy on selecting what instance is selected for termination is very limited and does not help me with this problem.

Comment: You mean EBS volume (or) EC2 instance?

Comment: EC2 instance <!-- -->

Comment: You may use CloudWatch & Lambda to achieve this. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/

Comment: While it should be possible to use CloudWatch to accomplish what you're asking, doing so is just a band-aid workaround to the underlying problem of why your CPU utilization is going up with "no load". There is no general problem with EB that would explain what you're seeing; the EB instances on one of my sites have been up continuously for over six months with no issues, for example. It sounds like you may have some sort of resource leak within your application.